# Mipmap icon changed in new project in android studio

Tags: android

I have found a question very similar to this but unanswered

I did a project named abc and it is published.Now i am creating another project for other customer.But As soon as i create a project i got two errors....

> 1.Cannot find a launcher_icon. So i have gone to mipmap folder and found that png is from my previous project and not default launcher
>   icon.It is hard coded and i am not able to change that.Any help
>   please...even if i create new project same error is coming..
>
> 2.Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'. >
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Users\My\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\23.0.0-preview\aapt.exe''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 1

For second error I am doing a play around and trying to solve but please help me for first error..